# ContentChild of nested Angular structural directive is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a structural directive A nested inside another structural directive B. 
Now i want to have access to B inside of A to use its templateRef.

I tried to use ContentChild, but it is always undefined.
Can somebody tell what I have to change to get access?

I recreated my constellation in a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b697ct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Directive definition:

```
@Directive({selector: '[testChild]'})
export class B {

}

@Directive({selector: '[testParent]'})
export class A {
  @ContentChild(B, {static: false}) contentTemplate: B;

  constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.contentTemplate); // logs undefined
  }
}

@Directive({selector: '[tstOutlet]'})
export class TestOutlet {
  constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tst',
  template: `<ng-container tstOutlet></ng-container>`,
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(A) parents: QueryList<A>;

  @ViewChild(TestOutlet, {static: true}) outlet: TestOutlet;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parents.toArray().forEach((parent: A) => {
      this.outlet.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(parent.templateRef);
    });
  }
}
```

Template definition:

```
<tst>
  <ng-container *testParent>
    <span *testChild>Test</span>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *testParent>
    <span *testChild>Second Test</span>
  </ng-container>
</tst>
```